# bootstrap react dropdown close button

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am new to react, one of our dropdown is full screen on mobile view so we need a close button within the menu.

```
const CloseMenu= (e) => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    // Some logic to close the dropdown
}
```

DropDown

```
<Dropdown>
  <Dropdown.Toggle variant="link">
    Dropdown Button
  </Dropdown.Toggle>

  <Dropdown.Menu>
    <Dropdown.Header>
        <h4>Menu Title</h4>
        <Button variant="link" onClick={CloseMenu}> X </Button>
    </Dropdown.Header>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
  </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```

I searching but couldn't find the solution. Kindly guide me, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs requirements are as following:

- When closed: on toggle click -> show dropdown
- When opened: on toggle click -> hide dropdown
- When opened: on "X" click -> hide dropdown
- When opened: on outside click -> hide dropdown

Make your *Dropdown* controlled by introducing a show state. Then define an *onToggle* handler:

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
```

...

```
<Dropdown show={show} onToggle={(isOpen) => setShow(isOpen)}>
```

When you click on "X", the dropdown is closed automatically. This is due to *Dropdown*'s property *autoClose*, which ist set to true per default;

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-lake-d0tfgi

Comment: doing so creates a now problem, the menu on desktop do not close when clicking anywhere outside the dropdown

Comment: I have fixed the bug. Please look into the sandbox agian.